# Magento Full Breadcrumb trail not showing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am having a problem with magento showing a full breadcrumb trail. For example, I have a CMS page located at `localhost:8080/link/nested-link`. The breadcrumb trail is only showing `Home > Nested Link`. It is completely missing the other link. Is there a programmatic way to solve this, or another resource that anyone knows of here? I have searched google more than once on this and can't seem to find a solution. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: The number 1 link when I searched Google was http://mage101.com/?p=228. That seemed pretty good to me. Otherwise my Google search came up with a lot of options. Can you try a solution and post where you get stuck rather than ask us to come up with a solution?

Comment: By default, Magento doesn't allow to create nested CMS pages. That means that all the pages are on the same level. And breadcrumbs are taken based on the real nesting level, not just URL. That's why it's not working in your case. The best way is to find an extension that allows to create a tree of CMS pages.